# How to make a tree only editable inline (no creation, no deletion) in Odoo8?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, tree, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to make a tree editable inline. I don't want to be able to create or remove records from that tree.

So what I did is the next:

```
<tree string="Event participants" create="false" delete="false" editable="bottom">
```

But this is not working properly, because when I set the parameter `create` to `false`, the **Save** button disappears, and the only way to save the changes made on a record is to click on other one after the modification (which is a bit confusing).

If I set `create` to `true`, the button **Save** appears again but also the **Create** button, which I don't want. I tried several combinations (`edit="true"`, `editable="top"`, `editable="bottom"` with both `create="false"` and `create="true"`) but I didn't achieve my purpose.

Can anyone help me here, please?

**EDIT**

XML code of the tree view:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_event_participant_diploma_tree">
    <field name="name">ei.event.participant.diploma.tree</field>
    <field name="model">ei.event.participant</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="17"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Event participants" create="false" delete="false" editable="bottom">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="surname"/>
            <field name="parent_id"/>
            <field name="tin"/>
            <field name="diploma"/>
            <field name="diploma_delivered"/>
            <field name="state"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Python code of the function which opens the tree view:

```
@api.multi
def open_diploma_management(self):
    tree_view_id = self.env.ref(
        'event_ina.view_event_participant_diploma_tree').id
    for event in self:
        return {
            'name': 'Diplomas management',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'views': [(tree_view_id, 'tree'), ],
            'res_model': 'ei.event.participant',
            'domain': [('event_id', '=', event.id)],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'current',
            'flags': {'action_buttons': True},
        }
```

Comment: When you set `create="false"` only the `Add new item` will be hidden, and the `save` button should appear after you clicking on `Edit` button, I've been trying your combination `create="false" delete="false" editable="botton"` and it working properly, please share your code with as to be able to help you more.

Comment: Thank you @JuanSalcedo, I've edited my question to show all the code which should be affecting to the tree view.